# How to capitalize all characters of input for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `<%=f.text_field :name %>` in my html.erb file. How would I make it so that all the characters are capitalized when the user creates or updates the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **capitalize ** method to capitalize a string with ruby
example:
In your controller you can use

```
name.capitalize()
```

in the frontend html you can use html for a quick feedback to the user
example:

```
input {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to create or update records you can use the before_save callback in your model, for example if you have an user model with the name field you can do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_create { |user| user.name = user.name.capitalize }
end
```

This will ensure that before creating or updating the database the field will be converted before the transaction.

Also, capitalize will just do the first letter uppercase, if you want to transform everything to uppercase please use `user.name.upcase`.